# Circular picture same width and height auto scaling the images

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to create a card like structure where I want to display and image and some text.
This is my result:
[image: Page]
I like most of the result, it just bothers me that not all images have this 5rem x 5rem size.
How can I solve this?
It would appear that the width / height of the `.card-img-holder` does not always fit 5x5.

```css
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
    padding: .5rem;
    margin: .5rem;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.card-img-holder {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
}

.card-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.card-img-name {
    padding: .5rem;
}

.card-img-name p:first-of-type {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- Jest -->
<div class="card">
  <div class="flex-container centered">
    <div class="card-img-holder">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/335/150" alt="Jest" class="card-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="card-img-name">
      <p>Jest</p>
      <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://jestjs.io/">Website</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- React -->
<div class="card">
  <div class="flex-container centered">
    <div class="card-img-holder">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/350" alt="React" class="card-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="card-img-name">
      <p>React</p>
      <p>Frontend Library</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://reactjs.org/">Website</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Git -->
<div class="card">
  <div class="flex-container centered">
    <div class="card-img-holder">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/63/150" alt="Git" class="card-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="card-img-name">
      <p>Git</p>
      <p>Version Control</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://git-scm.com/">Website</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `object-fit: cover;` for  `.card-img;`

Comment: Makes the item unviewable when the image is too broad and doesn't resolve the aspect ratio problem.

Comment: cover respects the ratio and cuts it on the sides ( if a landscape or a portrait, it ain't a square) , you can also use object-position, defaut is 50% 50% to choose which portions is to be seen (top bottom right left center or %/px/...)